# PHP: Copy select element option onto other page

Tags: php, html

sorry for the title as I am unaware what this method is called.

Basically I have a form on my home page, I then have another form on a different page. When a user selects an option from the select element I want to copy the results that the user selected on the home page.

How can this be done?

I have the following code so far:

```
<form class="car-finder-container" method="GET" action="used-cars.php">
         <select name="min-price" id="priceMax" class="select-box form-control price-min price-selector">
             <option value="min-price">Min price</option><option value="0">£0</option><option value="500">£500</option><option value="1000">£1,000</option><option value="1500">£1,500</option><option value="2000">£2,000</option><option value="2500">£2,500</option><option value="3000">£3,000</option><option value="3500">£3,500</option><option value="4000">£4,000</option><option value="4500">£4,500</option><option value="5000">£5,000</option><option value="5500">£5,500</option><option value="6000">£6,000</option><option value="6500">£6,500</option><option value="7000">£7,000</option><option value="7500">£7,500</option><option value="8000">£8,000</option><option value="8500">£8,500</option><option value="9000">£9,000</option><option value="9500">£9,500</option><option value="10000">£10,000</option><option value="11000">£11,000</option><option value="12000">£12,000</option><option value="13000">£13,000</option><option value="14000">£14,000</option><option value="15000">£15,000</option><option value="16000">£16,000</option><option value="17000">£17,000</option><option value="18000">£18,000</option><option value="19000">£19,000</option><option value="20000">£20,000</option><option value="22500">£22,500</option><option value="25000">£25,000</option><option value="27500">£27,500</option><option value="30000">£30,000</option><option value="35000">£35,000</option><option value="40000">£40,000</option><option value="45000">£45,000</option><option value="50000">£50,000</option><option value="55000">£55,000</option><option value="60000">£60,000</option><option value="65000">£65,000</option><option value="70000">£70,000</option><option value="75000">£75,000</option><option value="100000">£100,000</option><option value="250000">£250,000</option><option value="500000">£500,000</option>
         </select>
         <select name="max-price" id="priceMin" class="select-box form-control price-max price-selector">
             <option value="max-price">Max price</option><option value="0">£0</option><option value="500">£500</option><option value="1000">£1,000</option><option value="1500">£1,500</option><option value="2000">£2,000</option><option value="2500">£2,500</option><option value="3000">£3,000</option><option value="3500">£3,500</option><option value="4000">£4,000</option><option value="4500">£4,500</option><option value="5000">£5,000</option><option value="5500">£5,500</option><option value="6000">£6,000</option><option value="6500">£6,500</option><option value="7000">£7,000</option><option value="7500">£7,500</option><option value="8000">£8,000</option><option value="8500">£8,500</option><option value="9000">£9,000</option><option value="9500">£9,500</option><option value="10000">£10,000</option><option value="11000">£11,000</option><option value="12000">£12,000</option><option value="13000">£13,000</option><option value="14000">£14,000</option><option value="15000">£15,000</option><option value="16000">£16,000</option><option value="17000">£17,000</option><option value="18000">£18,000</option><option value="19000">£19,000</option><option value="20000">£20,000</option><option value="22500">£22,500</option><option value="25000">£25,000</option><option value="27500">£27,500</option><option value="30000">£30,000</option><option value="35000">£35,000</option><option value="40000">£40,000</option><option value="45000">£45,000</option><option value="50000">£50,000</option><option value="55000">£55,000</option><option value="60000">£60,000</option><option value="65000">£65,000</option><option value="70000">£70,000</option><option value="75000">£75,000</option><option value="100000">£100,000</option><option value="250000">£250,000</option><option value="500000">£500,000</option>
         </select>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block car-search-button btn-lg btn-success"><span class="glyphicon car-search-g glyphicon-search"></span> Search cars
         </button>
</form>
```

I then have the identical form on my other page apart from the method="GET" and action="used-cars.php" that I have added to this form.

How can I amend my second form to show the option that has been selected on the first page, any ideas?

Comment: Alternatively you could use SESSION.
Aside from that: seems that you have switched the ids of the options.

Answer (score 0):

In a static way:

You will have to store his selection in a cookie/HTML5 web SQL database (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)/ normal database.

While opening the home page, you have to read the current chosen options.

In a dynamic way:
I believe you will need Ajax and and database for that, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is for `min_price`

You have to change other value as well like this

`<input type="text" name="Any_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['min_price'];?>">`

**Very Important Note:** if you read the answer i used `min_price`, instead of `min-price` in short. Instead of dash `-` i used underscore `_`. You cant use dash. as `php` think you are doing math and its a minus sign.

so your input field in this has to be change as well

One i am doing Rest you can do it your self

select tag

```
<select name="min_price" id="priceMax" class="select-box form-control price-min price-selector">

<option value="min_price">Min price</option><option value="0">£0</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookie:

```
//php
//POST selection to your server side code then set cookie
$userMin= $_POST['min-price'];
$userMax = $_POST['max-price'];

$cookieData = json_encode(array('min'=>$userMin, 'max'=>$userMax));

//set cookie to be accessed across whole domain. Change '3600'!
setCookie('userSearchPreference', $cookieData, '3600', '/');

//get options on other pages
if (isset($_COOKIE['userSearchPreference']))
{
  $userPreferences = json_decode($_COOKIE['userSearchPreference']);
  //then set the'userMin' value on the frontend
}
```

There are others way of course. Hope this helps. Btw, if your user changes their min/max price you just need to reset the cookie and it will be overwritten with new values.

Comment: Thanks, tried using this however I'm getting a syntax error any idea why?

Comment: @PeterHardy (isset($_COOKIE['userSearchPreference'])) <- missing last bracket

Comment: Okay thanks, so just to make sure I have got this right, I am including all of that code in it's own PHP file, I then use a PHP include underneath the form to add it to my homepage and the other page with the form. IS this correct?

Comment: @PeterHardy 
 
Everything up to the isset() goes in the PHP file which your search form is handled by so that the cookie is essentially created when they search. Then on every other page you need/want to use those search paramters you check the cookie. You just need to access them like $userPreferences['min-price'] etc..

Comment: So I have added that exact code just below my form block of code, the results are still not being saved, any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Just checked code and working fine. You need to change the expiry time. Try adding time()+ infront of it.

setCookie('userSearchPreference', $cookieData, time()+'3600', '/');

Use Firebug to check the cookies, you can see it sitting in there :).

Comment: Hi, yes I can see that it is being added to my URL which is a good thing however the select elements aren't being selected, here is my live site: http://www.drivencarsales.co.uk/index.php

Could you possibly take a brief look to see why it might be going wrong, sorry for my ignorance. Btw if you do take a look just select a Min and Max price on the home page then press search and you will notice if you press the Price Range that the select elements inside arn't selected. Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly, the company I work for builds car dealership CMS for their stock and websites :). Regarding your site, there is no cookie set on the homepage nor the used-cars.php. I'd be happy to take a look at your code if you paste some snippets in. My email is on my profile, feel free to send it to that.